# How to avoid the 0 of "unnumbered chapter" in equations

Tags: equations, numbering, unnumbered-sections

**EDIT:** I knew I was forgetting something! I have edited the question to show how to properly do it.

I have a koma-script book (my PhD thesis) that number its equations (and tables, figures, etc.) within chapters.

How do I deal with an unnumbered chapter (for instance, the introduction) and avoid the dumb *eq. (0.1)* that appears (but of course keep the nice *eq. (1.1)* of the following chapter)?

I have not found an easy way to do it, and the trick that I tried

```
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=0 %
    
  \else
    \thechapter.
  \fi
  \arabic{equation}%
}
```

provides an ugly space *(1. 1)* that I don't see how to purge.

EDIT: It is sufficient to add a % symbol like this: `\thechapter.%`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{srcbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Unnumbered introduction}
    \begin{equation}
        a = 1
    \end{equation} 

    \chapter{Numbered chapter}
    \begin{equation}
        b = 2
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The easier approach would be to `\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}` and then `\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}` at the first numbered chapter.

Comment: True, I should have added that I am using this method at the moment. But I wanted something more general for reproducibility, as I am releasing also my thesis template and this was bugging me.